# How to create a ParseFile if I already have the URL from an existing ParseFile?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Suppose I already have the url from an existing ParseFile.

How can I assemble a new ParseFile using that url? I didn't find any way to do this yet. The ParseFile's constructors do not allow me to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once ParseFile is saved to the cloud you should associate it with an object. Next time when you would need it again, you should fetch the object associated with the file and use it for further actions, e.g. reference the file on other objects.

In order to create a file from the url you must use cloud code which has options for generating file from `uri`. This allows you to call a function whenever you need new file.

```javascript
Parse.Cloud.define('createFileFromUrl', (req) => {
  
  // Get URL and name from request
  const name = req.params.name
  const uri = req.params.uri
  
  // Initialize Parse.File from uri
  const parseFile = new Parse.File(name, { uri })
  
  // save and return the created file
  return parseFile.save(null, { useMasterKey: true })
})
```

But this is not reasonable when we are using urls from existing ParseFile, because we are now creating another ParseFile in parse server that's pointing to the file already saved by parse server.